# Drupal on CentOS / RedHat

Tags: linux, centos, cms, lamp, drupal

I have just setup a fresh installation of CentOS in VM form.  I want to try and test out Drupal.

What is the best way to install Drupal?  I have not installed LAMP yet.

Comment: For questions specific to Drupal you can also check http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *easiest* way is to install the Drupal package included with Fedora:

```
su -c 'yum install drupal'
```

However, I understand there are some differences from the stock version, so for a production installation you will probably want to install the official version manually.  But for testing purposes, that should do fine.

Comment: Will this command install everything required, i.e. even the LAMP stack?

Comment: It will install Apache and PHP but you will need to install MySQL separately.  (Drupal works with many different databases so the Fedora packagers wisely decided not to force one to install with it.)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to download a preconfigured VM from Bitnami and run it in a virtual environment like VMWare, Virtualbox, Hyper-V etc.